# $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval iff all numbers lying between the endpoints are contained in $I$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that for a set $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

> $I$ is an interval $\iff \forall x,y \in I \,\forall z \in \mathbb{R}: x \le z \le y \implies z \in I$

I struggle with the "$\impliedby$" direction: For $I$ closed I can choose $x,y$ as the endpoints and then all real $z$ in between are in $I$ which is pretty much the definition of an interval. But what if $I$ is open?

Comment: What is your definition of an interval?

Comment: @SahibaArora We didn't have a general definition. There was just each type mentioned, e.g. a closed interval $[a,b] := \{x \in \mathbb{R} \,|\, a \le x \le b\}$. Is there even a general abstract definition of an interval? Wikipedia also states only the separate cases.

Comment: @philmcole The result you want to show is generally taken as the definition.

Comment: There is no problem when $I$ is open. It says $\forall x,y \in I$. If $I$ is open, then $x,y$ will be inside $I$, not at the end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In particular, take $x=\inf I$ and $y=\sup I$ (can be $\pm \infty).$

Then we have $I=(\inf I,\sup I)$ or $I=(\inf I,\sup I]$ or $I=[\inf I,\sup I)$ or $I=[\inf I,\sup I].$ In each case, $I$ is an interval.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you stated for I to be an interval is called convex.
Convex subsets of a linear order, besides the whole order,  are of the form
(a,b), (a,b], [a,b), [a,b], (<-,b), (<-,b], (a,->), [a,->).
The last four are rays. . 
Convex is a general definition of interval.
What definition of interval are you using?